# Description of splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

In section 3.2.1 of [these notes](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter3.pdf) it is said the splitting field of a polynomial $f$ over $\Bbbk$ is a field $L=\Bbbk(\alpha_1,\dots ,\alpha_n)$ over which $f$ splits ($(\alpha_1,\dots ,\alpha_n)$ are the roots of $f$).

I don't understand a detail in one direction of the proof: why does $f$ split over $\Bbbk(\alpha_1,\dots ,\alpha_n)$? I mean why can we write a polynomial as a product of linear factors if its roots are all present in the field (ring?)?

Comment: You can write a  polynomial $f$ as a product of linear factors in this case because we can always use the factorization $f(x) = (x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...(x-\alpha_n)$, where the $\alpha_i$ are the roots of $f$.

Comment: @QuinnGreicius But why does such a factorization exist?

Comment: @user321480 : you mean why $\prod_i (x-a) = C f(x)$ for some constant $C$ ? because if a polynomial $P(x)$ (of $\mathbb{K}[x]$ where $\mathbb{K}$ [is a integral ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain)) have some root $a \in \mathbb{K}$ (such that $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{K}$ ?) , then there is a polynomial $Q(x) \in \mathbb{K}[x]$ such that $Q(x)(x-a) = P(x)$ (suppose there is no such $Q(x)$, and show  that in that case $P(a) \ne 0$ )

Comment: It may not be possible to factor $f$ into linear terms in the field $k.$ E.g. $f(x)=x^2+1$ cannot be factored into linear  terms over the reals. The  splitting field  $k(a_1,...,a_n)$  contains $k$ as a sub-field. And if $h$ is a sub-field of $k(a_1,...,a_n)$  with $h\supset (k\cup \{a_1,...,a_n\})$  then $h=k(a_1,...,a_n).$ E.g. if $k=Q$ and $f(x)=x^2-3$ then the splitting field is $\{a+b\sqrt 3: a,b\in Q\}.$  Theorem:Splitting fields exist.